# AWS SQS PHP Library - Is there an alternative to the full AWS PHP Library?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I'm looking to implement the AWS SQS services into one of my applications, however I'd rather not shove the entire AWS library into my application when I only use 2 specific services (S3 and SQS). S3 of which I use https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class. I unfortunately cannot find any standalone clients for SQS :|

Are there any other options besides putting the entire AWS library into my application? If it comes down to it I'll just rip out the components I need that are required for SQS, but I'd rather not do that for the sake of updates and whatnot.

Comment: You could create a build script (e.g. ant) that deletes the parts of the library that you are not using. That way you can build afresh from a Git repo, and accept upstream changes as they occur, while also maintaining your smaller preferred footprint in your production environment.

Comment: I'm curious, what are your concerns with the size of the AWS SDK?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why this is a problem. We're not in the stone ages of PHP anymore, and Composer is the best invention since peanut butter. You're not _actually_ still bundling the source code for all of your dependencies into your application repo, are you⁈ Because that would be insanity. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: ^ Yep, definitely was, and definitely just discovered composer about 5 days ago after posting this.. So not anymore haha..